# What is the opposite of love?

Tags: love, nonduality

There have been many questions about what love is, ranging from non-attachment and compassion. I am not looking for a clear definition of the opposite of love, i.e. what love isn't, but feel free to do so if you think it can help answer the question. Rather, I want to know if love can exist without suffering: in much the same way that happiness cannot exist without suffering. I don't mean to equate love with happiness but love does have an element of joy to it. So, to what extent is pain the opposite of love? Or, to what extent can pain be separated from love? Principle of non-duality answers this, but I want to hear other opinions.

Comment: I don't think this question is asked in the right frame of reference to be answerable from Buddhist perspective with references to either texts or verbal tradition or experience. The way this question is asked the answers will tend to be opinions and philosophizing by the authors.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov Any question has a degree of opinion to it, the extent to which that opinion is backed with facts and references is entirely up to the author. The nature of Buddhism is that every thought leads to the next(or is inter-connected) and limiting questions to a specific standard defeats the purpose of asking questions. I can see how this question doesn't work in other stackexchange communities but at some point this rule becomes an obstacle.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov Outside of being a moderator, do you have anything interesting to add to this question? That is what I am here for after all.

Comment: Yes, IMO the opposite of love is judgment. Pain is just something that comes from attachment to one of the sides in a judgment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83444/discussion-on-question-by-user29568-what-is-the-opposite-of-love).

Answer (score 3):

Loving kindness(Metta) is a state of the mind that arises and vanishes. It's not something that exists. For loving kindness to arise, one should see the lovable nature of beings. It does not require suffering. On the other hand, compassion requires seeing the helplessness in those overwhelmed by suffering.

Happiness is also a state of mind that arises and vanishes. It does not require suffering. Happiness arises even in the minds of enlightened beings.

Far enemy of love is hatred/aversion. Near enemy of love is lust.

Comment: Happiness and suffering are inseparable: if a person has never suffered, how can one know what happiness is?

Comment: Perhaps include delusion as third part of dukkha and not-metta? Insight requires absence of delusion.

Comment: @user29568 you can distinguish a happy feeling from a neutral feeling. Enlightened beings only have happy thoughts and neutral thoughts. They are fully aware of it when happiness arise in the mind.